# Is there a difference between Heaven and Paradise?

Tags: heaven

When Jesus was on the cross during his crucifixion, He said to one of the thieves " (Luke 23:43) And Jesus said unto him, Verily I say unto thee, Today shalt thou be with me in Paradise." After he was resurrected in the morning of the first day he said to Mary, "don't touch me as I have not ascended to My Father" who is obviously in Heaven.

If he promised to be in Paradise with the thief and has not entered into Heaven, so are Heaven and Paradise different, and If they are different, what was Jesus doing there in Paradise and not going to His Father?

Comment: This is a good question, and it points to the limitations of the "space/time" conundrum when facing eternity. You might want to check [this answer](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/486/2479) as it may have relevance to your question.

Comment: You're comparing across gospels (and not quoting the actual verse from John.) As phrased this is really a systematic theology question. If you want to ask about how the different gospels use these words then please [edit] this to ask do explicitly.

Comment: I think this is a good linguistic question - in Hebrew sometimes a distinction is made between sheol, ghenna, etc. The same could be true of Heaven.

Comment: @curiousdannii  all the 4 Gospels say about the same life of jesus don't they,but only differ in perspective and language style of the 4 writers

Comment: @RikkuJoseph But this is exactly that: a question of the language of the writers. First you have to deal with the language of the writers separately, and only then can you deal with them systematically.

Comment: @curiousdannii  Aare you sure that this a problem related to language.then you are completely right

Comment: That's up to you to decide. You could ask systematically at the Christianity site, or about the texts here.

Comment: Please focus on a specific text/author. For instance, what is the difference in Luke's Gospel?

Comment: If you can provide a more definitive example of the use of Heaven, instead of implying it "obviously", that would greatly improve the question.

Answer (score -1):

> Our Father which art in heaven,
>   Hallowed be thy name.
>   Thy kingdom come.
>   Thy will be done, in earth as it is in heaven ...
>   -- Matthew 6:9-10

There is no doubt that [heaven is the realm in which the Father dwells](https://www.blueletterbible.org/search/search.cfm?Criteria=father+in+heaven&t=KJV#s=s_primary_0_1), where its citizens prefer to do His will, and that earth is the realm in which the Father does not dwell, and where its citizens prefer to do their own will.

[Sheol](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/Lexicon/Lexicon.cfm?strongs=H7585&t=KJV) is the place of the dead, which is part of this realm. Clearly, the Father doesn't dwell in Sheol.

---

At the beginning of the biblical narrative, in Genesis, we are told that the "Tree of Life" was in the garden of Eden from which Adam and Eve were expelled, having chosen their own will over the Father's. This, of course, would have brought chaos to Eden for eternity, so, the Father considered it better to place them outside its gates in a realm of their own, which they could trash if such was their will.

Putting them out of Eden gave them something that they did not possess when they where within -- the capacity to discover for themselves which is best: the Father's will, or their own.

> And the LORD God said, Behold, the man is become as one of us, to know good and evil: and now, lest he put forth his hand, and take also of the tree of life, and eat, and live for ever: Therefore the LORD God sent him forth from the garden of Eden, to till the ground from whence he was taken. So he drove out the man; and he placed at the east of the garden of Eden Cherubims, and a flaming sword which turned every way, to keep the way of the tree of life.
>   -- Genesis 3:22-24 (KJV)

---

At the conclusion of the biblical narrative (according to the Christian canon), in Revelation, readers are told that the "Tree of Life" will be in the paradise of God, from which all overcomers will be invited to eat.

> He that hath an ear, let him hear what the Spirit saith unto the churches; To him that overcometh will I give to eat of the tree of life, which is in the midst of the paradise of God.
>   -- Revelation 2:7 (KJV)

Readers of Revelation are also told the purpose the Tree of Life will serve:

> And he shewed me a pure river of water of life, clear as crystal, proceeding out of the throne of God and of the Lamb. In the midst of the street of it, and on either side of the river, was there the tree of life, which bare twelve manner of fruits, and yielded her fruit every month: and the leaves of the tree were for the healing of the nations.

And how one is to overcome and, thus, obtain access to the Tree of Life:

> Blessed are they that do his commandments, that they may have right to the tree of life, and may enter in through the gates into the city.
>   -- Revelation 22:14 (KJV)

---

### Additional Comments

When the thief closed his eyes on this realm, he would open them again in the next ([1 Corinthians 15:51-52](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%2015%3A51-52&version=KJV&interface=print)). Any time that might pass for humanity between closing and opening his eyes would be unnoticed by him. When the thief does opens his eyes, however, he will do so in a different body (suitable for eternity) on a different earth, with a different heaven (canopy of stars), and Jesus will be there as his King and Lord.

Jesus, of course, had some loose ends to tie up on earth before he could join the thief in heaven, all of which would take place before the thief opened his eyes. Jesus is not constrained by time and space and is freely able to move between the heavenly and earthly realms.

---

### Conclusion

Is there a difference between Heaven and Paradise?

No. According to the biblical narrative Heaven, Eden, Paradise, and the City are all terms that distinguish the realm of the Father from the realm of men, i.e. the realm of peace, prosperity and life from the realm of chaos, destruction and death.

The more hearts in the realm of men that are inclined towards the commandments of God, the more it will resemble the realm of the Father, which He has declared is His will. Such a state, however, is not what is prophesied for the realm of men.

Comment: If it is same then how can Jesus be there with the theif and say to Mary that I have not entered into heaven three days later

Comment: When the thief closed his eyes on this realm, he would open them again in the next. Time for him would be immaterial. When the thief opens his eyes, he will do so in a different body (suitable for eternity) on a different earth, with a different heaven (canopy of stars), and Jesus will be there as his king and lord. Jesus, of course, had some loose ends to tie up before he could join him, all of which took place before the thief open his eyes. You may have overlooked the fact that Jesus is not confined by time and  space.