# In Matthew 25:1-13, who do the 5 foolish virgins represent?

Tags: matthew

In Matthew 25:1-13, are the five virgins Christians? If so can they lose their salvation? (v12 truly I tell you I don't know you) or are they losing their inheritance, as they all had lamps?

Comment: All ten had lamps. But five were so foolish they seem to think that the bare apparatus produces light. They lit the dry wick and it fizzled out. But the wise knew that oil was needed to produce light. And the oil they had was their own personal supply. What marks out the inferior five is their virginity, their lamp, their folly and their lack of oil. But the other five had virginity, lamp, wisdom, oil, light, and - ultimately - a marriage and an husband.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are the 'ten virgins' told in Jesus' parable multiple brides or just general wedding party?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/406/are-the-ten-virgins-told-in-jesus-parable-multiple-brides-or-just-general-wed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the difficulties of this passage is that we must work to read it as a first-century listener would hear the parable rather than a later reader looking back. In the early church - particularly Augustine - there was a tendency to allegorize Jesus' parables into thinking that wouldn't have been with Jesus in the original setting. This was a popular way of interpreting parables for many years.

We also have the tendency to read information back into the text or ask questions of the text that aren't really there - called [eisegesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisegesis). It takes some work to avoid this because we just aren't familiar with the cultural, historical, or religious context of the 1st-century Jewish thinking of Jesus' audience.

This has led many modern scholars to reassess how we have interpreted parables over the years. A few of those scholars:  [Kenneth Bailey](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0830825681); [Joachim Jeremias](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0334012147) or [Brad Young](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0801048206)

The parable in question concerns being prepared at any moment for the coming judgment of God.

Jesus is using the "known" concept of engagement/wedding from the first-century culture to help explain the "unknown" timing of God's judgment. His 1st-century Jewish audience would be familiar with this metaphor.

The metaphor of God as the groom and Israel as the bride goes far back in Israel's history. This metaphor is used to describe the relationship between the two parties. Since God is abstract - they use a concrete metaphor to help our minds understand the nature of the relationship better. For instance, the prophet Jeremiah uses the metaphor of the bride and groom in [Jeremiah 2](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Jeremiah%202%3A1-2&version=NIV). The New Testament extends this metaphor to Jesus and the Church.

The second cultural metaphor is the engagement/wedding party which has been explained elsewhere in [this forum](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/406/are-the-ten-virgins-told-in-jesus-parable-multiple-brides-or-just-general-wed) so I won't go into it fully. The main idea is that in ancient Israel an engagement period would last about a year, but in reality, it was only the groom's father who knew the exact date or hour that he would allow his son to go get his bride.

If you happen to be a bride pledged to be married then you must wait patiently for your groom to arrive. You also must be prepared. In a larger village - there may be any number of young women waiting for their groom.

A parable about the "wise" vs the "foolish" would be familiar to Jesus' audience as well. Here is another example of a parable comparing the wise and foolish from [the Jewish Talmud](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.153a?lang=bi):

> Similarly, Rabban Yoḥanan ben Zakkai said the following story as a parable to this
>   lesson: The situation is comparable to a king who invited his servants to a feast and did
>   not set a time for them to come. The wise among them adorned themselves and sat at the entrance to the king’s house. They said: Is the king’s house missing anything necessary
>   for the feast? Certainly, the king could invite them at any moment. The fools among them
>   went to attend to their work and said: Is there such thing as a feast without the toil of 
>   preparing for it? While the feast is being prepared, we will attend to other matters.
>
> Suddenly, the king requested that his servants come to the feast. The wise among them entered before him adorned in their finest clothes, and the fools entered before him dirty. The king was happy to greet the wise ones and angry to greet the fools. The king said: These wise servants who adorned themselves for the feast shall sit and eat and drink, but these fools who did not adorn themselves for the feast shall stand and watch. There is a similar outcome for people who think that their day of death and judgment is far away and do not prepare themselves for it.
>
> Babylonian Talmud, Shabbat 153a

Jesus' parable (Matt. 25:1-13) is a call to be prepared for the "unknown" day and hour of one's death and judgment. Jesus ends the parable with the command to "keep watch!"

> "Therefore keep watch, because you do not know the day or the hour." Matthew 25:13

Answer (score 1):

Ellicott cooments on the general framework of this famous parable:

> On the general meaning of the symbolism of the Wedding Feast enough
>   has been said in the Notes on Matthew 22:2. Here, as there, we have to
>   remember, that while the bride is the Church in her collective unity,
>   the contrasted characters of the members of the Church are represented
>   here by the virgins, as there by the guests who were invited; and for
>   this reason, probably, the bride herself is not introduced as part of
>   the imagery of the parable. As far as the frame-work of the figure is
>   concerned, the stage in the marriage rites which is brought before us
>   is the return of the bridegroom, after the espousals have been
>   completed in the house of the bride’s father, to his own abode,
>   bringing the bride with him. Jewish custom required the bridesmaids to
>   wait at the bridegroom’s house, to receive him and the bride, and as
>   this was commonly after sunset, they were provided with lamps or
>   torches.

It is significant that this parable sets up two classes of people called the wise and foolish virgins.  They have great similarities:

- All were invited to the wedding (see above)
- All were virgins symbolising purity, see Rev 14:5.
- All had lamps, ie, lights symbolising Christ as the light of the world, John 1:4, 9, 8:12, 9:5, Matt 5:14-16.
- All, at least initially had oil - but this is the crux of the parable - five virgins had enough oil and five did not have enough.  Therefore, the key to understanding this parable is to understand the symbol of oil as far as the Christian life is concerned.

The symbol of oil in ancient Israel was significant because it was used to anoint kings and priests, etc, to sacred office, Ex 30:23-25; see also Gen 31:13, Ex 28:41, 29:7, 36, 30:26, 40:11, Lev 8:12, 16:32, 1 Sam 9:16, 15:1, 16:3, 12, 2 Sam 2:4, 5:3, 1 Kings 1:34, 19:16, etc.  However, in the NT, this symbol was taken as a representing the anointing of the Holy Spirit, Luke 4:18, Acts 10:38, 2 Cor 1:21, 22, 1 John 2:20.

Thus, the distinction being made here is the adequacy of the supply of the Holy Spirit's anointing which is not limited by the will of God but by the decision of the recipient.  Ellicott observes in commenting Matt 25:3 -

> Took no oil with them.—In the interpretation of the parable, the lamp
>   or torch is obviously the outward life of holiness by which the
>   disciple of Christ lets his light shine before men (Matthew 5:16), and
>   the “oil” is the divine grace, or more definitely, the gift of the
>   Holy Spirit, without which the torch first burns dimly and then
>   expires. The foolish virgins neglected to seek that supply, either
>   from the Great Giver, or through the human agencies by which He
>   graciously imparts it.

Barnes makes a similar conclusion, presumably based on Gal 5:22, 23 about the fruit of the Spirit in the life of the Christian when he comments on Matt 25:3:

> The one part was "wise" in taking oil, the other "foolish" in
>   neglecting it. The conduct of those who were "wise" refers to those
>   who are "prepared" for the coming of Christ - prepared by possessing
>   real piety, and not being merely his professed followers. The conduct
>   of those "without" oil expresses the conduct of those who profess to
>   love him, but are destitute of true grace, and are therefore
>   unprepared to meet him.

Note that, as shown above, the foolish virgins are members of the church who are "called" (= invited) to the marriage and even have oil (the gift of the Holy Spirit) but conduct their lives so as to final extinguish the regenerating influence of the Spirit in their lives and thus are finally excluded from the marriage.

Comment: There is no evidence in the text that the foolish had any oil at all. Nor that the lamps of the ten were lit, prior to the cry awaking them. The theory of lit lamps going out and the 'supply' of oil running out is not there in the bare text.

Comment: @NigelJ - that is untrue.  Matt 25:8 records the cry of the foolish virgins who say, "our lamps are goin out"; that is, they had been alight but were perilously low on oil.  Note the verb σβέννυνται which every version translates as "are going out".

Comment: The word _kosmeo_ (KJV 'trimmed') conveys the adding of something extra to the lamp. The Greek is more clear. No oil was taken by the foolish. They had _no oil_. Their lamps were going out because they were attempting to light a bare wick, which cannot sustain the ignition. They had no oil. But I am not arguing the point and not down-voting you. Traditionally, everyone seems to accept what you say. It is just that the Greek does not support tradition, in this case.

Comment: @NigelJ - That is your understanding.  I would like to so some evidence of that assertion.  One does not take a lamp without oil in the first place.  Further, "trimming" the lamp specifically involved cutting away the burned part of the wick.  But you are welcome to your opinion (which sounds very Calvinistic??)

Answer (score 1):

The foolish virgins had oil in their lamps to begin with, because at midnight they said, “Our lamps are going out.” They just didn’t have extra jars of oil to replenish their lamps halfway through the night. Like the servants who become hypocrites (Mt 24:48-51) and the talent-burying servants (Mt 25:18, 24-30), the foolish virgins apostatize.

The important question is, why? It’s certainly not about buying the Holy Spirit or reserving Him for future days. I believe there are two possible reasons.

1. They thought they had enough oil because they believed He was coming back earlier in the night. (Think about this...)
2. They didn’t know what to expect as far as when He’d come, but they assumed it would all pan out.

I discuss this parable some more on my website. I invite you to check it out more here: https://overcomingthetribulation.com/about

Also, on the subject of apostasy, I recommend my blog, “Count the Cost and Stay Salty”: https://overcomingthetribulation.com/count-cost-stay-salty/

God bless!

Comment: "Apostatizing" sounds strong. Could "denying himself" or "losing his soul-life" in Mt 16:24-25 be related to 25:9-10's, or Rv 3:18's, "buy[ing]"? In other words, was Peter "apostatizing" in Mt 16:22-23? Could Scripture like "for even as the sufferings of the Christ abound unto us, so through the Christ our comfort also abounds. But whether we are afflicted, it is for your comforting and salvation; or whether we are comforted, it is for your comforting, which operates in the endurance of the same sufferings which we also suffer..." (2 Cor 1:4-7) exemplify, in some way, "reserving" the Spirit?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the five foolish virgins, as well as the five wise, are Christians, as this parable isn't about the coming judgment of God in a general sense, or toward nonchristians (nondiciples); but about

​​
"the sign of Your coming and of the consummation of [this] age," Mt 24:3.​​

​​
This is the context for 24:1--25:30. Nor is the parable about the coming of death. ​​

​​
"And while the bridegroom delayed, they all became drowsy and slept. But at midnight there was a cry, Behold, the bridegroom! Go forth to meet him! Then all those virgins arose and trimmed their own lamps."

​​
​​
25:5-7 seems to signify that these virgins of Christ (cf 2 Cor 11:2---though that may address the entire church in Corinth) died before Christ returns, then resurrect to meet Him (cf Jn 11:11-14, 43; 1 Thes 4:13-16). Needless to say, John was a first-century Jewish listener to Jesus' parable, as well as a first-century writer, and Paul also should have been a first-century Jewish reader and/or hearer of Matthew's record. Jesus the Jew, the One who spoke Mt 25, spoke in Jn 11:​

​
"He said to them, Our friend Lazarus has fallen asleep; but I am going that I may wake him out of sleep. The disciples then said to Him, Lord, if he has fallen asleep, he will recover. But Jesus had spoken about his death, but they thought that He was speaking about taking rest in sleep. So Jesus then told them plainly, Lazarus has died...And when He had said these things, He cried out with a loud voice, Lazarus, come out!"
 ​
"We do not want you to be ignorant, brothers, concerning those who are sleeping, that you would not grieve even as also the rest who have no hope. For if we believe that Jesus died and rose, so also those who have fallen asleep through Jesus, God will bring with Him. For this we say to you by the word of the Lord, that we who are living, who are left remaining unto the coming of the Lord, shall by no means precede those who have fallen asleep; Because the Lord Himself, with a shout of command, with the voice of the archangel and with the trumpet of God, will descend from heaven, and the dead in Christ will rise first."​

​
Though the Lord explains his use of the word "sleep" for death, in Jn 11, death is universal enough such that we, 20 centuries later, or folks 20 centuries prior, should've understood the metaphor. If anything, the first-century disciples in Jn 11 seem not to have understood initially that He was using a metaphor. I am fascinated and appreciate much to hear and learn of customs from distant times and places. But, like idioms or similes for death, marriage and marriage celebration are culturally universal phenomena, that, especially in the Gospels and Bible (divinely-composed and meant to communicate good news and truths around the world, cf 2 Tim 3:16; Mt 28:18-20; Ac 1:8; Jn 20:30-31), require no special or imaginary 'first-century-Jewish-audience understanding' to grasp.​

​
"But you shall receive power when the Holy Spirit comes upon you, and you shall be My witnesses both in Jerusalem and in all Judea and Samaria and unto the uttermost part of the earth."​

​
Ac 1:8 should be a word that Matthew the apostle grasped. Augustine's interpretation, at least in his Sermon 43 on the New Testament, identifies the oil possibly as love or a good conscience, "five" as our senses, lamps as good works; he correctly identifies that the virgins have died physically; he correctly identifies them as Christians, also quoting 2 Cor 11. He ties Christ's coming with the Day of Judgment. He maybe discusses sin too much in his discussion of the judgment. I'll stop here with Augustine.

For certain, marriage is 'the' theme of the Bible, which begins and ends with one, Gen 2:18-24; Rv 19:7-9; 21:2; 22:17, and, as others here point out, is riddled with throughout (Isa; Jer; Exo; Eph; Cor; Mt; Jn; Hosea...). It's no one less than God, in the Lamb, as the Lamb, who gets married in the Apocalypse, who courts and sanctifies Israel and the church, and who was "put to sleep" to produce a counterpart, typified by Eve at least 6,000 years ago.​

​
"Christ also loved the church and gave Himself up for her that He might sanctify her, cleansing her by the washing of the water in the word, that He might present the church to Himself glorious," Eph 5:25-27.​

​
The second, compound, question interpreting the parable was: Can [believers] lose their salvation, or are they losing their inheritance, as they all had lamps? It seems the questioner already has interpreted Jesus' word "lamps," and so I'd love to hear it. It's midnight, the darkest time, one can say, so I can see why the women need lamps. What is it that all believers possess related to containing the light? Actually all human beings possess a body, soul, and spirit, since that's how God made us, Gen 2:7; 1 Thes 5:23. But I'd love to hear the questioner's understanding of "lamps." An answerer answers that the lamps symbolize the light, and yet to me, whether in first- or 21st-century context, more finely: lamps hold or contain light. One verse is Proverbs 20:27 which reads:​

​
"The spirit of man is the lamp of Jehovah searching all the innermost parts of the inner being."​

​
The five foolish virgins also had lamps lit. Which to me means that they're born again. Born anew. Born from above, born of God and of the Spirit (oil's symbolism). Where? In their human spirit (Mt 5:3; Jn 3:6; Rm 8:16). In other words: all are New Testament disciples, believers. Like Matthew, Peter, John themselves all became regenerated when they breathed in the Christ in Jn 20:22. The "vessel" then should be the [extra] container of the oil, which in Biblical anthropology is our human soul. Our person. Us. "Vessels" in both the Old and New Testament are people. God's the Potter, we're the clay. "Vessels" also are particularly our bodies, in 1 Sam 21:5 and 1 thes 4:4. But here, in Mt 25's parable, the Spirit of God must firstly indwell our soul before He transfigures and glorifies us by reaching our body. If these virgins are deceased, none of them as yet would be resurrected and have 'much' oil in their bodies. What is "trimming"? I believe it equates to turning to one's spirit, Rm 8:2. Setting the mind on the spirit. Who are those who sell? What does buying mean? I believe it equates to losing the soul-life. That we may gain it in the next age. Losing our life to gain His life. How to go to those who sell? I'll try to leave those unanswered for now. All must be meaningful and relevant to our Christian life in a specific way. Another Scripture where "buying" is referenced is Rv 3:18-21, to the complacent local church:

"I counsel you to buy from Me gold refined by fire that you may be rich, and white garments that you may be clothed and that the shame of your nakedness may not be manifested, and eyesalve to anoint your eyes that you may see. As many as I love I reprove and discipline; be zealous therefore and repent. Behold, I stand at the door and knock; if anyone hears My voice and opens the door, then I will come in to him and dine with him and he with Me. He who overcomes, to him I will give to sit with Me on My throne, as I also overcame and sat with My Father on His throne."

Finally, lastly, the questioner's real, central, question, his crux, seems to be about "losing salvation." I repent and apologize that I didn't...begin with this question first. But then...other things came up. Perhaps someone else or I can. Suffice it to say now that, just as in the accompanying parable of the "talents," and the rest of the New Testament: it's impossible for one predestinated and born of God to become "unreborn." Just as it is to be unborn. Such a thing isn't real, doesn't exist. However, God judges His children, separately, and He will be fair and just. Not disturbing our eternal destiny, but whether we, for example, participate in His Millennial kingdom reign, or not. Rv 2--3's words about "overcoming" describe both rewards and punishments. And it is only by grace that one can both begin the Christian life, and overcome.

"Therefore receiving an unshakable kingdom, let us take grace, through which we may serve God well-pleasingly with piety and fear; for our God is also a consuming fire,"

Heb 12:28-29, (1-3)

Answer (score 0):

Peace.

The foolish (who are church goers who proclaim they know God) are those who will hear the “cry” made but will not rejoice in what they hear as the Lord comes to give us an understanding by the opening up of the Scriptures to our hearing ears.  They will not praise Him as they do not “go out to meet Him” (outward praise of God).

They will have no joy (the oil of gladness) towards what they hear and will not outwardly praise God nor have thanksgiving.   They will not joy nor be filled with the Holy Spirit….nor will they be able to as they turn away from what they hear and so are prevented from entering into to know the mysteries of the kingdom.   They will not enter in to the fullness of the “joy of the Lord”.

Their “lamps are gone out” as they do not outwardly praise God for what they hear the Bridegroom saying as they do not have the inward joy (the “oil” of gladness) to motivate them to praise.

> Matthew 25:6-8 KJV (6)  *And at midnight **there was a cry made,** Behold,
>   the bridegroom cometh; go ye out to meet him. (7)  Then all those
>   virgins arose, and trimmed their lamps. (8)  And the foolish said unto
>   the wise, Give us of your oil; for our lamps are gone out.*

As John the Baptist said,  the friend of the Bridegroom which stands and hears Him, rejoices greatly because of His voice…and so the joy is fulfilled greatly.  One can then enter in to the fullness of the  “joy of the Lord”.

> John 3:29-33 KJV (29)  *He that hath the bride is the bridegroom: but
>   the friend of the bridegroom, which standeth and heareth him,
>   **rejoiceth greatly because of the bridegroom's voice: this my joy
>   therefore is fulfilled.** (30)  He must increase, but I must decrease.*

The wicked instead go back to the “earthly” men who preach their own private interpretations as those they hear retail the Word of God without understanding.

We are not redeemed with their things that they preach for money’s sake.  We are not to return to those who “sell” and “buy” what they are preaching as there is no joy in those things…and we are not redeemed by their things preached in their earthly understanding nor can we enter in to know the mysteries.

> (31)  *He that cometh from above is above all: **he that is of the earth
>   is earthly, and speaketh of the earth: he that cometh from heaven is
>   above all**.*

The Son’s testimony of heavenly things (the Scriptures are interpreted in their true heavenly interpretation by His voice) is above all of earthly men’s private interpretations and we are to hear Him….receiving His testimony with joy so we can enter in to know the true sayings of God.  He must increase and our own understanding...our own thoughts and ways...must decrease at the hearing of His knowledge.  No earthly, natural man will receive His testimony as they consider what they hear as foolishness.

> (32)  ***And what he hath seen and heard, that he testifieth; and no man
>   receiveth his testimony.*** (33)  He that hath received his testimony
>   hath set to his seal that God is true.

We must not return to the “corruptible things” received by the transmission (“traditions”) of our church fathers.   We must not buy what they have been selling for such a long time now.   They preach another “Jesus” (many false christs) and another good news.

> 1 Peter 1:18-19 KJV (18)  **Forasmuch as ye know that ye were not
>   redeemed with corruptible things, as silver and gold, from your vain
>   conversation received by tradition from your fathers;** (19)  But with
>   the precious blood of Christ, as of a lamb without blemish and without
>   spot:

We must rejoice in what we hear the Bridegroom saying.   The "new wine" is to be put in "new bottles"...those who renew their minds to His righteousness.  They will receive what they hear Him saying in joy.

> Luke 5:37-39 KJV (37)  *And no man putteth new wine into old bottles;
>   else the new wine will burst the bottles, and be spilled, and the
>   bottles shall perish. (38)  **But new wine must be put into new bottles;
>   and both are preserved**.*

But those who are used to the old teaching of the Scriptures of earthly men will not at once desire the new teaching of our Lord as they think that the "old" is better.  They return back to their churches' teachings and commandments and reject what they hear if they cannot overcome.

> (39)  **No man also having drunk old wine straightway desireth new: for
>   he saith, The old is better.**

Why “buy” the things that they preach and command? Their things do not satisfy as there is no real joy in them.  Why spend money for that which is not “bread”… which is not the Bread of Heaven…the testimony of the Son?  The preaching of false prophets are motivated by the receiving of our money.

> Isaiah 55:1-3 KJV (1)  *Ho, every one that thirsteth, come ye to the
>   waters, and he that hath no money; come ye, buy, and eat; yea, come,
>   buy wine and milk without money and without price.*

Those who will hear diligently unto Him will be able to eat that which is good as they will be able to receive all of the mysteries of Heaven as the Lord opens up the Scriptures to our hearing ears.   "Let your soul delight in fatness"…that is, to JOY in what one hears Him say.    Our “soul shall live”…..that is, it will rejoice greatly at the hearing of His voice.

> (2)  *Wherefore do ye spend money for that which is not bread? and your
>   labour for that which satisfieth not? **hearken diligently unto me, and
>   eat ye that which is good, and let your soul delight itself in
>   fatness. (3)  Incline your ear, and come unto me: hear, and your soul
>   shall live**; and I will make an everlasting covenant with you, even the
>   sure mercies of David.*

The wicked foolish will not hear and will not rejoice but rather reject what they hear and return to their previous church things and will not be able to enter in.

They will not have known the day nor the hour in which the Son of man came to their hearing ears.  They heard His voice but did not rejoice in what they heard and went backward and not forward into the knowledge of the Lord.

> Matthew 25:8-13 KJV (8)  *And the foolish said unto the wise, Give us
>   of your oil; for our lamps are gone out. (9)  But the wise answered,
>   saying, Not so; lest there be not enough for us and you: **but go ye
>   rather to them that sell, and buy for yourselves. (10)  And while they
>   went to buy, the bridegroom came; and they that were ready went in
>   with him to the marriage: and the door was shut.** (11)  Afterward came
>   also the other virgins, saying, Lord, Lord, open to us. (12)  But he
>   answered and said, **Verily I say unto you, I know you not. (13)  Watch
>   therefore, for ye know neither the day nor the hour wherein the Son of
>   man cometh.***

We must keep the loins of our minds girded with His righteousness and be “sober” and not drunk on the wine of wrath towards what we shall hear Him saying as He opens up the Scriptures….interpreting them….with His voice.

We are to respond to the hearing of His voice (the revelation of the true Jesus who is called the Christ) in holiness and not return to the envy and strife of our previous  fighting over church things that were done in ignorance as they served "another jesus" as preached by their church fathers. Jesus "Barabbas" = Jesus son of the father=another jesus as preached by the church fathers.

> 1 Peter 1:13-16 KJV (13)  **Wherefore gird up the loins of your mind, be
>   sober, and hope to the end for the grace that is to be brought unto
>   you at the revelation of Jesus Christ;** (14)  As obedient children, not
>   fashioning yourselves according to the former lusts in your ignorance:
>   (15)  But as he which hath called you is holy, so be ye holy in all
>   manner of conversation; (16)  Because it is written, Be ye holy; for I
>   am holy.

The Son of man comes at an hour we think not…and so we must be always be waiting on the Lord having our minds girded with the Truth and doing things in His righteousness so that we may enter in immediately when we hear His voice. He will serve them with the "meat" of the Truth as they will be able to "eat" of the mysteries of the kingdom as there will be greater revelation of the Scriptures to their minds.

> Luke 12:35-40 KJV (35)  *L**et your loins be girded about, and your
>   lights burning; (36)  And ye yourselves like unto men that wait for
>   their lord, when he will return from the wedding; that when he cometh
>   and knocketh, they may open unto him immediately.** (37)  Blessed are
>   those servants, whom the lord when he cometh shall find watching:
>   verily I say unto you, that he shall gird himself, and make them to
>   sit down to meat, and will come forth and serve them. (38)  And if he
>   shall come in the second watch, or come in the third watch, and find
>   them so, blessed are those servants. (39)  And this know, that if the
>   goodman of the house had known what hour the thief would come, he
>   would have watched, and not have suffered his house to be broken
>   through. (40)  Be ye therefore ready also: for the Son of man cometh
>   at an hour when ye think not.*

The wicked will not hear and will instead choose to do evil in the hearing of His voice.  They will not be waiting and ready.  They will not enter in to know the mysteries.

His servants will be able to drink in and  “eat” what they hear and will rejoice (joy of heart) while those who will not hear and rejoice will be ashamed of what they hear and will grieve it and will not be able to enter in to know the mysteries.   They will not be able to receive what they hear as they shall go “hungry” and thirsty.

> Isaiah 65:12-14 KJV (12)  *Therefore will I number you to the sword,
>   and ye shall all bow down to the slaughter: **because when I called, ye
>   did not answer; when I spake, ye did not hear; but did evil before
>   mine eyes, and did choose that wherein I delighted not.** (13) 
>   Therefore thus saith the Lord GOD, Behold, my servants shall eat, but
>   ye shall be hungry: behold, my servants shall drink, but ye shall be
>   thirsty: behold, my servants shall rejoice, but ye shall be ashamed:
>   (14)  **Behold, my servants shall sing for joy of heart, but ye shall
>   cry for sorrow of heart, and shall howl for vexation of spirit**.*

His words…His "angels"..…the true and faithful sayings of God will sever the wicked from among the just.

The wicked will not receive His words when they will hear them. They will be ashamed of His words and will not rejoice.  Their judgment then will be final as the hearing of His words will produce “gnashing of teeth” among the unbelievers.

Instead of rejoicing at what they hear, they will instead wail and gnash their teeth in rage at it and will persecute those who will receive it after they have been severed from among the just who will receive His words. Their own evil words shall bring themselves torment as their tongues are a "fire".

> Matthew 13:49-50 KJV (49)  So shall it be at the end of the world: **the
>   angels shall come forth, and sever the wicked from among the jus**t,
>   (50)  And shall cast them into the furnace of fire: there shall be
>   wailing and gnashing of teeth.

Answer (score 0):

The oil is a fuel.  "So He humbled you, allowed you to hunger, and fed you with manna which you did not know nor did your fathers know, that He might make you know that man shall not live by bread alone; but man lives by every word that proceeds from the mouth of the Lord".

"Still other seed fell on good soil, where it produced a crop—a hundred, sixty or thirty times what was sown. Whoever has ears, let them hear.” Gethsemane means oil press.

We are saved by God's grace, but the fruits of repentance will show. How can our conduct surpass that of the Pharisees if we stand in the corner and say "thank goodness I am not like them"?
We should not be at all dismissive of the Old Testament that foretold the coming of our Saviour. God set the flaming sword at the gate of heaven. Jesus is the way, the truth and the life. He is the sword of truth.

He came as the 'servant'. The servant is also the central pillar of the menorah that upholds the central light, the Word of God, and is the light for the other branches. The almonds are the first fruits of the trees in the Spring of the Holy Land.

Some say the menorah represents the tree of life.

Comment: Please add some references to support you assertions.

Comment: Also, the question is asking about the five foolish bridesmaids, and it's not very clear what you're saying they represent.

Comment: Hi Cleethorpes, welcome to BH.SE - great to see you're already getting some constructive feedback from the community for improving your first answer. I'd also recommend taking the [Site Tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) when you get a chance to learn more about the site and how it all works. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Church Father Quotes also Prove that the “Oil” Speak of “Good Works especially the CHARITY DOCTRINE” for the Parable of 5 Wise vs 5 Foolish Virgins Parable (Matthew 25:1 – 14)

1. St. Jerome of the Vulgate

> This parable of the ten foolish and the ten wise virgins, some interpret literally of virgins, of whom there are according to the Apostle [marg. Note: 1 Cor 7] some who are virgins both in body and in thought, others who have preserved indeed their bodies virgin, but have not the other deeds of virgins, or have only been preserved by the guardianship of parents, but have wedded in their hearts. But from what has gone before, I think the meaning to be different, and that the parable has reference not to virgins only, but to the whole human race. ... Or, These virgins who complain that their lamps are gone out, shew that they are partially alight, yet have they not an unfailing light, nor enduring works. Whoso then has a virgin soul, and is a lover of chastity, ought not to rest content with such virtues as quickly fade, and are withered away when the heat comes upon them, but should follow after perfect virtues, that he may have an enduring light. ... For these wise virgins do not answer thus out of covetousness, [p. 849] but out of fear. Wherefore, each man shall receive the recompense of his own works, and the virtues of one cannot atone for the vices of another in the day of judgment. The wise admonish them not to go to meet the bridegroom without oil, “Go ye rather to them that sell, and buy for yourselves.” ... And this oil is sold, and at a high cost, nor is it to be got without much toil; so that we understand it not of alms only, but of all virtues and counsels of the teachers. ... But because the [p. 850] season for buying was now past, and the day of judgment was coming on, so that there was no room for penitence, they must not now lay up new works, but give an account of the old. ... After the day of judgment, there is no more opportunity for good works, or for righteousness, and therefore it follows, “And the door was shut.” ... Their worthy confession calling Him, “Lord, Lord,” is a mark of faith. But what avails it to confess with the mouth Him whom you deny with your works? ...  For “the Lord knoweth them that are his,” [2 Tim 2:19] and he that knoweth not shall not be known, and though they be virgins in purity of body, or in confession of the true faith, yet forasmuch as they have no oil, they are unknown by the bridegroom. When He adds, “Watch therefore, because ye know not the day nor the hour,” He means that all that has been said points to this, namely, that seeing we know not the day of judgment, we should be careful in providing the light of good works. ...” – Blessed St. Jerome of the Vulgate, Second Latin Doctor of the Church who did the First Official Translation of the Bible out of Its Original Languages into Latin, Priest, Confessor, Secretary to Pope Damasus I (c. 347 AD – c. 420 AD,  Commentary on Matthew 25:1 – 13’s Parable of the Five Wise/Foolish Virgins in catena Aurea)

2. St. Hilary of Poitiers

> The “oil” is the fruit of good works, the “vessels” are the human bodies in whose inward parts the treasure of a good conscience is to be laid up. ...  At the trumpet signal they go forth to meet the bridegroom alone, for then shall the two be one, that is, the flesh and God, when the lowliness of the flesh shall be transformed into spiritual glory. ... Or, the trimming their lamps is the return of their souls into their bodies, and their light is the consciousness of good works that shines forth, which is contained in the vessels of the body. ... They that sell are the poor, who, needing the alms of the faithful, made them that recompense which they desire, selling in return for the relief afforded to their wants, a consciousness of good works. This is the abundant fuel of an undying light which may be bought and stored up for the fruits of mercy. ... “The marriage” is the putting on of immortality, and the joining together corruption and incorruption in a new union. ... Yet though the season of repentance is now past, the foolish virgins come and beg that entrance may be granted to them. ...” …” – Blessed St. Hilary of Poictiers, the “Athanasius of the West”, Doctor of the Church, The Champion of Trinity in the West, Approved Church Father in the First Lutheran Father’s Book of Concord, Venerated in the Catholic Church, Eastern Orthodox Church, Oriental Orthodoxy, Anglican Communion, Lutheran Church  (c. 310 AD – c. 368 AD, Commentary on Matthew 25:1 – 13’s Parable of the Five Wise/Foolish Virgins in Catena Aurea)

3. Origen of Alexandria

> Or, The “oil” is the word of teaching, with which the vessels of souls are filled ; for what gives so great content as moral discourse, which is called the oil of light. The “wise” took with them of this oil, as much as would suffice, though the Word should tarry long, and be slack to come to their consummation. The, “foolish” took lamps, alight indeed at the first, but not supplied with so much oil as should suffice even to the end, being careless respecting the provision of doctrine which comforts faith, and enlightens the lamp of good deeds. ... Or, Whilst the bridegroom “tarried,” and the Word comes not speedily to the consummation of this life, the senses suffer, slumbering and moving in the night of the world; and sleep, as energizing feebly, and with no quick sense. Yet did those wise virgins not quit their lamps, nor despair of hoarding their oil. ... “ –  Blessed Origen of Alexandria, the Great but surprisingly Modest Exegete of the Eastern Church, “Nicknamed: Admantius or Man of Steel”, Tortured and Martyred for Christ who also was used by God to decide which of the available six Hebrew Bible Variants called the Hexapla was to be used for the Christian Church (c. 184 AD – c. 253 AD, Commentary on Matthew 25:1 – 13’s Parable of the Five Wise/Foolish Virgins in Catena Aurea)

4. St. Gregory the Great

> For in each of the five senses of the body there is a double instrument, and the number five doubled makes ten. And because the company of the faithful is gathered out of both sexes, the Holy Church is described as being like to ten virgins, where as bad are mixed with good, and reprobate with elect, it is like a mixture of wise and foolish virgins. ... It is to be observed, that all have lamps, but all have not oil. ... To sleep is to die, to slumber before sleep is to faint from salvation before death, because, by the burden of sickness we come to the sleep of death. ... Or, “All the virgins arose,” [p. 848] that is, both elect and reprobate are roused from the sleep of death; they “trimmed their lamps,” that is, they reckon up to themselves their works for which they look to receive eternal blessedness. ...  The lamps of the foolish virgins go out, because the works which appeared outwardly to men to be bright, are dimmed within at the coming of the Judge. That they then beg oil of the wise virgins, what is it but that at the coming of the Judge, when they find themselves empty within, they seek for witness from without? As though deceived by their own self-confidence, they say to their neighbours, “Whereas ye see us rejected as living without works, do ye witness to our works that ye have seen. ...” …” – Blessed Roman Catholic Pope St. Gregory the Great, Saint Gregory the Dialogist in Eastern Christianity, the Father of Christian Worship, and Protestant Reformer Blessed John Calvin declared in his Institutes that Gregory was the last good Pope, Approved Church Father in the First Lutheran Father’s Book of Concord (540 AD – 604 AD, Commentary on Matthew 25:1 – 13’s Parable of the Five Wise/Foolish Virgins in Catena Aurea)

5. St. John Chrysostom

> Hom. Lxxviii, In the foregoing parable the Lord set forth the punishment of the man who beat, and was drunk, and wasted [p. 844] his Lord’s goods; in this He declares his punishment who profits not, and does not prepare for himself abundantly the things of which he has need; for the foolish virgins had oil, but not enough. ... And He employs the character virgins in this parable to shew, that though virginity be a great thing, yet if it be not accompanied by works of mercy, it shall be cast out with the adulterers. ... Or, The “oil” denotes charity, alms, and every aid rendered to the needy; the lamps denote the gifts of virginity; and He calls them “foolish,” because after having gone through the greater toil, they lost all for the sake of a less; for it is greater labour to overcome the desires of the flesh than of money. ...  You see then how great merchants the poor are to us; but the poor are not there, but here, and therefore we must store up oil here, that we may have it to use there when occasion shall require. ... That, “While they went to buy,” shews that even, if we should become merciful after death, it will avail us nothing to escape punishment, as it was no profit to the rich man, that he became merciful and careful about those who belonged to him. ...” – Blessed St. John Chrysostom, Doctor of the Church, Archbishop of Constantinople, one of the Three Holy Hierarchs / Great Hierarch, Approved Church Father in the First Lutheran Father’s Book of Concord, Venerated in the Catholic Church, Eastern Orthodox Church, Oriental Orthodoxy, Anglican Communion, Lutheran Church   (c. 349 AD – c. 407 AD, Commentary on Matthew 25:1 – 13’s Parable of the Five Wise/Foolish Virgins in Catena Aurea)

6. St. Augustine of Hippo

> Lib. 83 Quaest, Q59: Or, “The lamps” which they carry in their hands are their works, of which it was said above, “Let your works shine before men.” [Matt 5:16] ... Or, by the five virgins, is denoted a five-fold continence from the allurements of the flesh; for our appetite must be held from gratification of the eyes, ears, smell, taste, and touch. And as this continence may be done before God, to please Him in inward joy of the conscience, or before men only to gain applause of men, five are called wise, and five foolish. Both are virgins, because both these men exercise continence, though from different motives. ... Or, The “oil” denotes joy, according to that, “God hath anointed thee with the oil of gladness.” [Ps 45:7] He then whose joy springs not from this that he is inwardly pleasing to God, has no oil with him; for they have no gladness in their continent lives, [p. 846] save in the praises of men. “But the wise took oil with their lamps,” that is, the gladness of good works, “in their vessels,” that is, they stored it in their heart and conscience, as the Apostle speaks, “Let every man prove himself, and then shall he have rejoicing in himself, and not in another.” [Gal 6:4] ... For there die of both kinds of men in this interval of time before the resurrection of the dead, and the Lord’s coming shall be. ... They “trimmed their lamps,” that is, prepared to give an account of their deeds. ... From habit, the mind seeks that which uses to give it pleasure. And these now seek from men, who see not the heart, witness to God, who sees the heart. But their lamps go out, because those, whose good works rest upon the testimony of others, when that is withdrawn, sink into nothing. ... Or we may suppose it not meant as advice what they should do, but as an indirect allusion to their fault. For flatterers sell oil, who by praising things false, and things unknown, lead souls astray, recommending to them, as foolish, empty joys, and receiving in return some temporal benefit. … Go ye rather to them that sell, and buy for yourselves,” i.e. Let us now see what they can profit you who have used to sell you their praise. “Lest there be not enough for us and you,” because no man is profited in God’s sight by the testimony of others, because God sees the heart, and each man is scarce able to give testimony concerning his own conscience. ... When they have been taken in who have been changed into angelic being, all entrance into the kingdom of heaven is closed; after the judgment, there is no more place for prayers or merit. [marg. Note: 1 Cor 15:51] ...  It is not said that they bought any oil, and therefore we must suppose that all their delight in the praise of men being gone, they return in distress and affliction to implore God. But His severity, after judgment, is as great as His mercy was unspeakable before. “But He answered [p. 851] and said, Verily I say unto you, I know you not;” by that rule, namely, that the art of God, that is, His wisdom, does not admit that those should enter into His joy who have sought to do in any thing according to His commandments, not as before God, but that they may please men. ... “ – Blessed St. Augustine of Hippo, Doctor of the Church, who influenced virtually all of subsequent Western philosophy and Catholic theology, as well as a significant amount of Protestant theology, Approved Church Father in the First Lutheran Father’s Book of Concord, Approved Church Father in the First Lutheran Father’s Book of Concord, Venerated in the Catholic Church, Eastern Orthodox Church, Oriental Orthodoxy, Anglican Communion, Lutheran Church     (c. 354 AD – c. 430 AD,  Commentary on Matthew 25:1 – 13’s Parable of the Five Wise/Foolish Virgins in Catena Aurea)

Source: [Patristic Bible Commentary](https://sites.google.com/site/aquinasstudybible/home/matthew-commentary/catena-aurea-on-matthew/chapter-1/chapter-2/chapter-3/chapter-4/chapter-5/chapter-6/chapter-7/chapter-8/chapter-9/chapter-10/chapter-11/chapter-12/chapter-13/chapter-14/chapter-15/chapter-16/chapter-17/chapter-18/chapter-19/chapter-20/chapter-21/chapter-22/chapter-23/chapter-24/chapter-25)

Comment: Source for each quote above:
 https://sites.google.com/site/aquinasstudybible/home/matthew-commentary/catena-aurea-on-matthew/chapter-1/chapter-2/chapter-3/chapter-4/chapter-5/chapter-6/chapter-7/chapter-8/chapter-9/chapter-10/chapter-11/chapter-12/chapter-13/chapter-14/chapter-15/chapter-16/chapter-17/chapter-18/chapter-19/chapter-20/chapter-21/chapter-22/chapter-23/chapter-24/chapter-25

Answer (score 0):

1. "... 8And the foolish said to the wise, ‘GIVE US SOME OF YOUR OIL, for our lamps are going out. ...GO RATHER TO THOSE WHO SELL, and BUY FOR YOURSELVES.’ ..." = The "Oil" is a obtained via THOSE WHO SELL (who are on the earth even at that time), as the FOOLISH understood it as an earthly transaction and went to buy
2. If the "Oil" was the "Most Blessed Holy Spirit of God", then the dialogue would have been entirely different, right? I mean "no" earthly buying and selling can buy the Holy Spirit of God! It sounds like a Blasphemy to claim so (risky).
3. If the "OIL" cannot be obtained via an earthly transaction or it's done for, then the WISE VIRGINS would have answered differently, right? That is, they would have said it cannot be obtained. So the fact that the foolish virgins returned later (obtaining the oil) refers to they tried or did perform some earthly transaction but the time was too late.
4. The "OIL" cannot refer to a Church Gathering simply because the "Wise" are already going away at that time and a gathering of the foolish or with 'those who sell' that remain on earth doesn't seem logical.
5. The "OIL" cannot refer to "Pre-Trib Rapture belief" because the "foolish ones were not left behind" but woke up also (i.e. Resurrected) meaning they were part of it & even spoke to the "Wise ones" (i.e. Pre-Trib raptured ones by assumption) but yet were "not saved".
6. "... 10And WHILE THEY WENT TO BUY,  ..." = The meaning is clear that an earthly transaction is implied and FIRST CHRISTIANITY TAUGHT WIDELY that this REFERS to the CHARITY DOCTRINE LIFESTYLE by RELATIVE MEASURE

Note: Since “… NO PROPHECY of SCRIPTURE is of ANY PRIVATE INTERPRETATION, …” (2 Peter 1:20), these FIRST CHRISTIANITY QUOTES are important for accurate meaning, right?
Conclusion

Blessed Martin Luther himself Taught that the "OIL" refers to "TRUE FAITH" where his definition of True Faith included the "LAMP" as the CHARITY DOCTRINE LIFESTYLE to HELP ONE's NEIGHBOUR to quote from Page 2578 of the #SafeRouteScripturallyBook:

“... Therefore, let each one see to it that he has these two together: the OIL, which is TRUE FAITH and trust in Christ; and the LAMPS, the VESSEL, which is the OUTWARD SERVICE TOWARD YOUR NEIGHBOR. The WHOLE CHRISTIAN LIFE CONSISTS in THESE TWO THINGS things: BELIEVE GOD. HELP YOUR NEIGHBOR. The WHOLE GOSPEL TEACHES this. PARENTS should TELL IT TO THEIR CHILDREN at HOME and EVERYWHERE. Children, too, should CONSTANTLY FOSTER THIS WORD AMONG THEMSELVES. I should really say something about the sleep of the virgins and about the setting out of the Bridegroom for the wedding. But the hour is late. Another time. May God be gracious to us! Amen. ...”- The First Champion of the Protestant Faith, Blessed Martin Luther’s Sermon which was translated in 2013 by the Rev. Paul A. Rydecki, On Faith and Good Works, Preached in Erfurt at St. Michaeliskirche on the Day of the 11,000 Virgins (October 21st), 1522
Source: http://www.godwithuslc.org/luther-sermon-for-trinity-27/

Note: Regardless if Martin Luther (above) quoted the “oil” and “lamp” as “faith” and “good works” respectively, it doesn’t change the meaning in essence that he is emphasizing clearly that the CHARITY DOCTRINE LIFESTYLE as signified in his phrase above as ‘OUTWARD SERVICE TOWARD YOUR NEIGHBOR’ is part of the “5 Wise Virgins” and he exhorts to “Preach it everywhere”, in his words “... BELIEVE GOD. HELP YOUR NEIGHBOR. The WHOLE GOSPEL TEACHES this. PARENTS should TELL IT TO THEIR CHILDREN at HOME and EVERYWHERE. Children, too, should CONSTANTLY FOSTER THIS WORD AMONG THEMSELVES. ...”. So we preach likewise and cannot be condemned for it either as we are following Martin Luther in this.

Comment: This is the fourth "Answer" you have posted for this question. Please use the [edit] under one of your answers to combine them together and then delete the remainder. Also, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).